# What is <title>(.*?)<\/title> and how the attacker use that?

Tags: webserver, web

I had a log from my web server like this

```
[28/Aug/2022:12:57:02] "GET / HTTP/1.0" 200 1684 "" "<title>(.*?)<\/title>"
```

What is this meaning and what exactly did the attacker want to do?

Comment: what's your LogFormat?

Comment: @kenlukas idk, I use CherryPy and this is the output when I run it.

Comment: FYI - https://docs.cherrypy.dev/en/latest/basics.html?highlight=logging#logging

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like a snippet of code with a regex in it, to get the page title by extracting the string between the title html tags.

I think that someone has not configured their bot/http crawler correctly and it's sending that in the request. It shouldn't be an issue unless it is is straining your bandwidth or if you don't want your site being crawled in that way. If so then you can ban by ip or create some kind of rule in your firewall to block those kind of requests.